# HttpURLConnection! Connection.getInputStream is java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception

I created a method "UPLPAD2" to upload file to server. Splitting my file to packets(10MB). It's OK (100%). But when i call getInputStream, i get FileNotFoundException. I think, in loop, i make new HttpURLConnection to set  "setRequestProperty". This is a problem. 
Here's my code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public int upload2(URL url, String filePath,
        OnProgressUpdate progressCallBack, AtomicInteger cancelHandle)
        throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream fileStream = null;  
    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    Log.e("Upload_Url_Util", url.getFile());
    Log.e("Upload_FilePath_Util", filePath);
    long total = 0;
    try {
        // Write the request.
        // Read from filePath and upload to server (url)
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePath); 
        long lenghtOfFile = (new java.io.File(filePath)).length();
        Log.e("LENGHT_Of_File", lenghtOfFile + "");

        int totalPacket = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
        int totalChunk = (int) ((lenghtOfFile + (totalPacket - 1)) / totalPacket);
        String headerValue = "";
        String contentLenght = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < totalChunk; i++) {
            long from = i * totalPacket;
            long to = 0;
            if ((from + totalPacket) > lenghtOfFile) {
                to = lenghtOfFile;
            } else {
                to = (totalPacket * (i + 1));
            }
            to = to - 1;
            headerValue = "bytes " + from + "-" + to + "/" + lenghtOfFile;
            contentLenght = "Content-Length:" + (to - from + 1);
            Log.e("Conten_LENGHT", contentLenght);
            connection = client.open(url);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", headerValue);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    Long.toString(to - from + 1));  
            out = connection.getOutputStream();
            Log.e("Lenght_Of_File", lenghtOfFile + "");
            Log.e("Total_Packet", totalPacket + "");
            Log.e("Total_Chunk", totalChunk + "");
            Log.e("Header_Valure", headerValue);

            int read = 1;

            while (read > 0 && cancelHandle.intValue() == 0
                    && total < totalPacket * (i + 1)) {
                read = fileStream.read(buf);
                if (read > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, read);
                    total += read;
                    progressCallBack
                            .onProgressUpdate((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                }
            }
            Log.e("TOTAL_", total + "------" + totalPacket * (i + 1));
            Log.e("I_", i + "");
            Log.e("LENGHT_Of_File", lenghtOfFile + "");
            if (i < totalChunk - 1) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            out.close();
        }
        // Read the response.
        response.setHttpCode(connection.getResponseCode());
        in = connection.getInputStream(); // I GET ERROR HERE.
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected HTTP response: "
                    + connection.getResponseCode() + " "
                    + connection.getResponseMessage());
        }
        byte[] body = readFully(in);
        response.setBody(body);
        response.setHeaderFields(connection.getHeaderFields());
        if (cancelHandle.intValue() != 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response.getBodyAsString());
        Log.e("Upload_Body_res_", response.getBodyAsString());
        if (jo.has("error")) {
            if (jo.has("code")) {
                int errCode = jo.getInt("code");
                Log.e("Upload_Had_errcode", errCode + "");
                return errCode;
            } else {
                return 504;
            }
        }
        Log.e("RESPONE_BODY_UPLOAD", response.getBodyAsString() + "");
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Http_UpLoad_Response_Exception", e.toString());
        response.setHttpCode(connection.getResponseCode());
        Log.e("ErrorCode_Upload_Util_Return", response.getHttpCode() + "");
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            return 1;
        } else if (connection.getResponseCode() == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return response.getHttpCode();
        }
        // Log.e("ErrorCode_Upload_Util_Return", response.getHttpCode()+"");
    } finally {
        if (fileStream != null)
            fileStream.close();
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

And Logcat

```
06-12 09:39:29.558: W/System.err(30740): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://download-f77c.fshare.vn/upload/NRHAwh+bUCxjUtcD4cn9xqkADpdL32AT9pZm7zaboHLwJHLxOPxUX9CQxOeBRgelkjeNM5XcK11M1V-x
06-12 09:39:29.558: W/System.err(30740):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:187)
06-12 09:39:29.563: W/System.err(30740):    at com.fsharemobile.client.HttpUtil.upload2(HttpUtil.java:383)
06-12 09:39:29.563: W/System.err(30740):    at com.fsharemobile.fragments.ExplorerFragment$7$1.run(ExplorerFragment.java:992)
06-12 09:39:29.568: W/System.err(30740):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 09:39:29.568: E/Http_UpLoad_Response_Exception(30740): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://download-f77c.fshare.vn/upload/NRHAwh+bUCxjUtcD4cn9xqkADpdL32AT9pZm7zaboHLwJHLxOPxUX9CQxOeBRgelkjeNM5XcK11M1V-x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the URL you open the connection with, actually exists. It's probably cause some typo in the URL or similar.

Comment: ok ,  i check it, when  i add Log.e("Conection_INFO_i:",i+"____"+connection.getContentLength()+"");
just to test connection, It's work. :D... But this's  a bad solution! Do you have any ideal?   @Christopher Francisco

Comment: In that case I believe the issue lies on your server-side. Something should be wrong so that you can't open a connection. I would try to access it on my computer's browser and if it can't connect, then you found your issue

Answer (score 7):

`FileNotFoundException` is `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()`'s way of giving you an HTTP 404 status. So the URL you are POST-ing to doesn't exist. If the response code you get isn't 200 you shouldn't call `getInputStream()` at all, you should call `getErrorStream().`

But you don't need all this code. Java will set the content-length for you, and your copy loop only needs to look like this:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

where `count` is an `int` and `buffer` is a `byte[]` of any size greater than zero, typically 8192. You don't have to worry about making it the same size as the file, or chunks, or any of that. Just set chunked transfer mode, and Java will figure it out.

Comment: OK but all the following remarks apply. It isn't valid to call `getInputStream` if you already know there is an error.